# Nativescript-vue pulling up keyboard breaks the builtin back button on Android

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

My component:

```
<template>
  <Page actionBarHidden="true">
    <ScrollView>
      <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar
          class="txt-md"
          hint="What are you looking for?"
          v-model="search_query"
        />
        <card-view v-for="(obj, index) in filtered_list" :key="index">
          <StackLayout>
            <image v-if="obj.image" :src="obj.image" />
            <StackLayout id="lbl-wrapper">
              <label class="txt-lg" textWrap="true" :text="obj.title" />
              <label class="text txt-md" textWrap="true" :text="obj.overview" />
              <label class="right txt-md dg">View More >></label>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
        </card-view>
        <label margin="10" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </Page>
</template>
<script>
  import searchFilter from "./searchFilter.js";
  export default {
    props: {
      objs: Object,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        search_query: "",
      };
    },
    computed: {
      filtered_list: function() {
        return searchFilter(this.objs, (o) => o.title, this.search_query);
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

And I navigate to it like so:

```
<template>
  <page>
    <GridLayout>
      <navBarItem
        @tap="goTo(item.page,item.props)"
      />
    </GridLayout>
  </page>
</template>

<script>
  import navBarItem from "./navBarItem.vue";
  import listView from "./listView.vue";
  import {faqs} from "./data.js";
  export default {
    components: {navBarItem},
    data() {
      return {
        item: {
          page: listView,
          props: {objs: faqs},
        }
      };
    },
    methods: {
      goTo(page, props) {
        this.$navigateTo(page, {
          frame: "content",
          props: props,
        });
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

So far I have only tested on android. I do have a bunch of other navigations in my app that are working just fine. I also have some popup navigations that work fine too. In fact this navigation that I posted works fine too. The only problem is that in these navigations that include the searchBar the android builting back button doesn't work.

What happens is that as soon as the page is opened the searchBar captures the focus and the keyboard comes up, then the back button changes to down button to pull down the keyboard, after pressing that, the back button doesn't work anymore. while it works just fine in every other navigation that I have done in my application.

In fact, if I go to the page containing the searchbar then go to another page, then go back, the keyboard won't come up and I would still be able to go back! so the problem is exactly that back button doesn't work after keyboard comes up.

The problem is definitely with the keyboard since:
If I go to a->b->c where b has the searchbar, I can go from c->b->a by pressing the back button twice, since when I go back to b the keyboard doesn't come up. however, if I got back to b from c and then manually click on the searchbar to pull up the keyboard and then pull the keyboard down, the back button won't work.

Comment: Generally SearchBar doesn't cause issues as such, I suspect it could be something specific to your code. Can you share a Playground sample where the issue will be reproduced?

Comment: It's not exactly the searchBar. It's the keyboard that affects the backbutton. searchBar steals the focus and opens up the keyboard and I don't want that but it's a different issue from the back button problem.

Comment: It's the default behavior of Android to focus the first focusable element on Page. But still that never affects your back button from functioning. If you want to remove focus from search bar, you could do that programatically or add another focusable view above search bar.

Comment: by programmatically you meany taking the focus away after it's gained? I would like to just never have it happen because I suspect that would produce a glitch/flash of the screen. I really don't think that the rest of my code can be in anyway related to this issue because I'm definitely not touching the history, in fact the word history does not even appear on my codebase! and also clearly the history is intact since after going to a new page and tapping back twice it works fine, also please note my latest edit.

Comment: It sounds like the expected behavior, the first back button action will be used to hide keyboard, then the second one controls navigation. To prevent focus you could use the solution I have linked above.

Comment: @Manoj I saw your great answer and that solved my autofocus issue. But the keyboard is still breaking the functionality of the mack button. please note that `a->b->c` are three different pages of which b has searchBar. if I go from a to b and then manually click on the searchBar to pull up the keyboard. the back button won't take me back to a even if I press it 100 times. however if I go to a new page like c,  then come back to b by pressing the back button and this time not click on the searchBar to pull up the keyboard, then pressing the back button would take me back to a.

Comment: As far I can tell navigation will never be blocked by keyboard appearance (except the first back button press will be considered for hiding keyboard). Please share a Playground Sample where your issue can be demonstrated and used for debugging.